# boolean value in case statement in sql query

Tags: sql, ado.net

I am using case statement in select query some thing like this.

```
Select col1, col2, isActive = case when col3 = 'abc' then 1  else  0 end, col4
from <tablename> where <some condition>.
```

when i read the 'isActive' column value in ado.net -

```
bool isActiveFlag = (bool)datareader["isActive"];
```

I get type cast error. because it is returning value as int.

If i change query to

```
Select col1, col2, isActive = case when col3 = 'abc' then 'true' else 'false' end, col4
from <tablename> where <some condition>.
```

I get same type cast error because this time returned value is string. Basically i want query to assign boolean value to 'isActive' in query, so that i can read it as boolean value.

```
bool isActiveFlag = (bool)datareader["isActive"];
```

Any idea how to deal with this ?

I don't want to read the value as int or string and then convert the value to boolean.

Comment: have you tried using Convert.ToBoolean instead of explicit casting?

Comment: @Waqas yes i can read value as string and do the Convert.ToBooleam. It is working for me. but i want to read the value as boolean rather than doing a boolean conversion.

Answer (score 6):

You could do:

```
bool isActiveFlag = (int)datareader["isActive"] != 0;
```

You didn't mention which dbms you are using, but if SQL Server you could do something like:

```
Select col1, col2, isActive = CONVERT(bit, case when col3 = 'abc' then 1  else  0 end), col4  from <tablename> where <some condition>
```

which should return your value as a bool making

```
bool isActiveFlag = (bool)datareader["isActive"];
```

work as expected.

If I'm not mistaken this is because SQL server per-se does not have a boolean datatype, so there is no way to specify a boolean literal in a query.  .NET maps the bit datatype to bool, but there is also no way to specify a bit-literal in a query string without using CONVERT or CAST. The literal `1` is interpreted as an int value as you've already seen.

Comment: i can read value as int or string and do the conversion to boolean. But i am wondering why cann't i read directly as bool.

Comment: i am using MS Sql server. yes CONVERT in query will work. thanks.But why do we need t do that ?

Comment: Because we have no way of specifying a literal of type 'bit' other than using CAST or CONVERT I believe.

Answer (score 3):

The right string values for boolean is 'True' and 'False', so use in your query:

```
Select col1, col2, isActive = case when col3 = 'abc' then 'True' else 'False' end, col4
from <tablename> where <some condition>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option :

```
declare @true bit = 1
declare @false bit = 0

Select col1, col2, isActive = case when col3 = 'abc' then @true else @false end, col4
from <tablename> where <some condition>
```

Probably overkill in this case, but maybe useful when your sql is multi-statement and you would reference the variables multiple times.