# Optimize splitting a column only when a character is present

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `UtilityPin` as below :

```
UtilityID   PinType    PinValue     PinLatitude  PinLongitude
---------------------------------------------------------------
ABC         Zip        90222-3804   33.903808   -118.240723
ABC         Zip        90230-4313   34.008245   -118.388507
ABC         Zip        90230-4941   34.003206   -118.396149
ABC         Zip        90230        34.001654   -118.395662
```

Now the `PinValue` column contains `Zip-Zip4` value for a region and I want to extract `Zip Zip4` from it and also when `Zip4` is not present for a row the format is `Zip` with no hyphen as can be seen in the last row which means `Zip4` must be blank.

So after researching and looking over some Stack questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376695/boolean-value-in-case-statement-in-sql-query), I ended up with following query:

```
Select
    Zip = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', h.PinValue) >0 THEN  SUBSTRING(h.PinValue, 0, CHARINDEX('-', h.PinValue)) ELSE h.PinValue END,
    Zip4 = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', h.PinValue) >0 THEN SUBSTRING(h.PinValue, CHARINDEX('-', h.PinValue) + 1, LEN(h.PinValue) - CHARINDEX('-', h.PinValue)) 
    ELSE '' END
FROM 
    UtilityPin h
WHERE 
h.UtilityID ='ABC'
```

Which working fine and giving the result I want but as you can see in above query I have to check the presence of `-` twice in `PinValue`, which is doing a redundant operation , as I have to split it up in two columns `Zip` and `Zip4`. Basically I want something like this:

```
--this query gives an error
Select 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', h.PinValue) >0
    THEN
        SUBSTRING(h.PinValue, 0, CHARINDEX('-', h.PinValue)) AS Zip, 
        SUBSTRING(h.PinValue, CHARINDEX('-', h.PinValue) + 1, LEN(h.PinValue) - CHARINDEX('-', h.PinValue)) AS Zip4 
    ELSE
        h.PinValue AS Zip, 
        '' AS Zip4 
from 
    UtilityPin h
WHERE 
    h.PinType ='ABC'
```

So I would check for `-` in `PinValue` only once but the above query is giving error, I have also used `IF..ElSE` but it is giving error.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken zip format is fixed therefore you can do this

```
SELECT LEFT(PinValue, 5) Zip,
       CASE WHEN LEN(PinValue) = 10 THEN RIGHT(PinValue, 4) END Zip4
  FROM UtilityPin
 WHERE UtilityID ='ABC'
```

or even

```
SELECT LEFT(PinValue, 5) Zip,
       SUBSTRING(PinValue, 7, 4) Zip4
  FROM UtilityPin
 WHERE UtilityID ='ABC'
```

Note: in the second query you'll get an empty string rather than `NULL` in `zip4` if a value doesn't contain last four digits. You can fix this with either way with `NULLIF()` or `COALESCE()`.

Sample output:

```
|   ZIP |   ZIP4 |
|-------|--------|
| 90222 |   3804 |
| 90230 |   4313 |
| 90230 |   4941 |
| 90230 | (null) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/175f6/4)** demo for both queries